# Magento:2 How to save unique values for my custom admin module

Tags: magento2, database, adminhtml, form-validation

I am making a custom admin module which store custom data. I want to save unique values in table field.

How I can check unique column value before save data, show error message if values already exist.

Which is the best way as per Magento standard?

Thank

Answer (score 1):

I think you should follow the same path which Magento follow in module `CMS` for  unique `cms block identifier` and unique `cms page url`, you can add `_beforeSave` method in your `ResourceModel` class and check your unique value.

In CMS block you can find this,

```
 protected function _beforeSave(AbstractModel $object)
    {
        if (!$this->getIsUniqueBlockToStores($object)) {
            throw new LocalizedException(
                __('A block identifier with the same properties already exists in the selected store.')
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

File path `vendor\magento\module-cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block.php`

From here you can get your starting point

Comment: Thanks Keyur. I will check your suggestion and update you.

Comment: Okay, hope It helps you :) @SHPatel

Comment: Accept  the answer If you find It helpful @SHPatel

Comment: How I can check customer exist or not by using this function?

Comment: Please see your question first, what you have asked, customer exist or not by using this function It seems that It is custom requirement.

Comment: You asked only way too achieve by Magento way nothing else @SHPatel

Comment: It's not my question solution. Can you give more proper answer?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback, then add more details in questions , so people can understand  :) @SHPatel

Answer (score 1):

I have created one slider module in which there is **slide** table linked with store tables. So I have any of slides does not have the same position based on store. For this, you need to add two tables, one is main table and the other is store table. Here in this case, there are tables **slide** and **slide_store** tables.

Check the below code to add tables.

```
<?php

namespace [Package_Name][Module_Name]\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        /**
         * Create table 'slide'
         */
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('slide')
        )->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Block ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'title',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Block Title'
        )->addColumn(
            'position',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['nullable' => true, 'default' => '0'],
            'Position'
        )->addColumn(
            'is_active',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '1'],
            'Is Block Active'
        )->setComment(
            'Slide Table'
        );
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        /**
         * Create table 'slide_store'
         */
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('slide_store')
        )->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Block ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'store_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            ['unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Store ID'
        )->addIndex(
            $installer->getIdxName('slide_store', ['store_id']),
            ['store_id']
        )->addForeignKey(
            $installer->getFkName('slide_store', 'entity_id', 'slide', 'entity_id'),
            'entity_id',
            $installer->getTable('slide'),
            'entity_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        )->addForeignKey(
            $installer->getFkName('slide_store', 'store_id', 'store', 'store_id'),
            'store_id',
            $installer->getTable('store'),
            'store_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        )->setComment(
            'Slide To Store Linkage Table'
        );
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

To use above table, you need to create three model files.

```
i.e.,

[Package_Name][Module_Name]\Model\Slide.php

[Package_Name][Module_Name]\Model\ResourceModel\Slide.php

[Package_Name][Module_Name]\Model\ResourceModel\Slide\Collection.php
```

Finally, to check the unique position based on store, you need to write **_beforeSave()** of **[Package_Name][Module_Name]\Model\ResourceModel\Slide.php**.

```
<?php

namespace [Package_Name][Module_Name]\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Slide extends AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('slide', 'entity_id');
    }

    protected function _beforeSave(AbstractModel $object)
    {
        if (!$this->checkIsUniquePosition($object)) {
            throw new LocalizedException(
                __('Position needs to be unique for each slide.')
            );
        }

        return parent::_beforeSave($object);
    }

    public function checkIsUniquePosition(AbstractModel $object)
    {
        if ($this->_storeManager->hasSingleStore()) {
            $stores = [Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID];
        } else {
            $stores = (array)$object->getData('stores');
        }

        $select = $this->getConnection()->select()
            ->from(['slide' => $this->getMainTable()])
            ->join(
                ['slide_store' => $this->getTable('slide_store')],
                'slide.entity_id = slide_store.entity_id',
                []
            )
            ->where('slide.position = ?', $object->getData('position'))
            ->where('slide_store.store_id IN (?)', $stores);

        if ($object->getId()) {
            $select->where('slide.entity_id <> ?', $object->getId());
        }

        if ($this->getConnection()->fetchRow($select)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix `$this->_storeManager` issue